# C#-Alter table tname add column cname Long Integer NOT NULL-throws exception

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, alter

I am creating tables and column dynamically.

First creating tables and then adding columns in them with alter table.

But whenever

```
ALTER TABLE TNAME 
ADD COLUMN CNAME LONG INTEGER NOT NULL
```

is executed, it shows an error in the alter table statement.

And when there is `DECIMAL(28,0) NOT NULL`, column is successfully added.

Database is MS-Access and using C#

what is wrong with long int

Comment: The access tag doesn't refer to ms-access database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JET SQL language there isn't a LONG INTEGER database type. You simply specify LONG or INTEGER.

I have tried your sql statement with Access Query Builder and it doesn't like that syntax. However you are right, if I remove the ending NOT NULL it accepts the statement although [looking here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/equivalent-ansi-sql-data-types-HP001032229.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP001032248) does not seem to be a valid syntax.

Comment: if i dont specify not null.then it works fine.it adds column with number datatype and LONG INTEGER field Type but when there is not null it throws error

Comment: YES THE TABLE IS EMPTY.I HAVE JUST CREATED A BLANK TABLE AND ADDING COLUMNS TO IT

Comment: Do not skip NOT NULL, skip INTEGER: `ALTER TABLE TNAME
ADD COLUMN CNAME LONG NOT NULL`

Comment: @Remou yes that's the correct way. However as OP pointed and I can confirm it, if I remove the NOT NULL the string with LONG INTEGER is accepted by the Jet Engine. It is strange to me.

Comment: YES,skipped integer and it is working.thank you very much to both of you.

Comment: there is one another thing while adding data to yes/no type it shows datatype mismatch.that query works in query design in ms access but in c# it gives error

Comment: Hi Steve This is the second time in the last week I have come across something similar and I am beginning to suspect that Access (Jet/ACE) will drop the last word if it is not relevant, so adding NOT NULL means that INTEGER is no longer the last word, and it stops working.

Comment: For example, this works `alter table table2 add column cola integer cat`, but I do not get a cat. Or a unicorn `alter table table2 add column colb integer unicorn`